# Java Calculator Error

Tags: java, variables, initialization, calculator

Before marking this all duplicate please look at the code as it is done in a different way than in other questions and I would appreciate a fix relating to this code.  It is pretty much a calculator that takes two numbers and an operator then prints the final number (and, if applicable, a remainder).  I get the errors:

```
The local variable num3 may not have been initialized

The local variable rem may not have been initialized
```

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JCalc {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int num1;
    int num2;
    int num3;
    int rem;

    System.out.println("Welcome to JCalc!  The best calculator ever!");
    System.out.print("Please enter the first number: ");

    num1 = myScanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Please enter the second number: ");

    num2 = myScanner.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Please enter an operator (+, -, %, *): ");

    String op = myScanner.next();

    if (op == "+") {
        num3 = num1 + num2;
    }

    if (op == "-") {
        num3 = num1 - num2;
    }

    if (op == "%") {
        num3 = num1 - num2;
        rem = num1 % num2;
    }

    if (op == "*") {
        num3 = num1 * num2;
    }
    System.out.print("The answer is: ");
    System.out.print(num3);  //error

    if (op == "%") {
        System.out.print(" with a remainder of ");
        System.out.println(rem);  //error
    }






}

}
```

The last 2 brackets got a little messed up when I copy pasted them (sorry).  Appreciate all the help I can get!

Comment: @MadProgrammer how is that a duplicate? He's not asking about comparing Strings

Comment: @abmitchell Yes, I know saw the `String` comparison code and jumped on it, my bad.  But once we solve the question he's just asked, they'll hit this problem as well :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler isn't the best at following multiple if conditions. I would change:

```
int num3;
int rem;
```

to

```
int num3=0;
int rem=0;
```

Now they'll be unconditionally initialized. Basically, you can't have local variables unassigned, though class fields are OK.

Anyway, you should use `equals(` for strings. Use `if("+".equals(op))` and such.

Comment: But when i put the =0 it makes all of my equations =0.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @TheBoss Read the last line of my post. Don't use `==` for string comparison. Instead use `if(op.equals("+"))` and such.

Comment: (Nit pick) `"+".equals(op)` to avoid possible `NullPointerException`s ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yes, understood. Since the method handles null nicely, right?

Comment: @hexafraction It's more a convention to save you from having to explicitly check for `null` than any possible error the OP might get right now.

Comment: Thanks for all the help!  Got it now.  Book I'm learning from hadn't covered this yet and I was just wondering if I could make a calculator without the book.

Answer (score 1):

In Java, all local variables must be declared before they can be used. The basic form of a variable declaration is shown here:

```
type identifier [ = value][, identifier [= value] ...] ;
```

The type is one of Java's datatypes. The identifier is the name of the variable. To declare more than one variable of the specified type, use a comma-separated list.

```
double pi = 3.14159; // declares an approximation of pi.
char x = 'x';        // the variable x has the value 'x'.
```

1. [local variables](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_variable_types.htm)
2. [local variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html)

Use the `String.equals(String other)` function to compare strings, not the `==` operator.
`==` compares the reference of the variable where `.equals()` compares the values which is what you want.

1. [string comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

Comment: *"all variables must be declared before they can be used*" - Not true. Instance variables are initialized to a default value by the JVM - Nit pick to be sure ;)

Comment: There's certainly no harm in setting a default value to a instance variable, but it's just not always required ;)

Comment: Now mention the `String` comparison so we can start getting some up-voting going ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer: Sir, I did changes. Thanks for paying attention and help correcting my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Both variables should be initialized with a default value, this is a compiler warning.

`num3` is never assigned outside of an if statement, so technically it could never be assigned (in the eyes of your compiler). This isn't good, so it throws that warning, same with `rem`.

It doesn't throw warnings for the other two since they are forcibly assigned by the blocking method `Scanner.nextInt()`

Answer (score 0):

`String` comparison is not done via the `==` mechanism.  This compares the memory address of the objects, not their contents

Instead use `"+".equals(op)` instead

See [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for more details

Java makes no gurentees to what values are assigned to local variables.  This means, to be sure, you should always assign your own default values, for example.

```
int num1 = 0;
int num2 = 0;
int num3 = 0;
int rem = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Initialize your variables

   int num3=0;
   int rem=0;
2. Compare your string using equals() method.

Compare the variable 'op' using equals() method instead of '=='.

```
if (op.equals("+")) {}
```

Or if you want to use '==' itself to compare, then take the help of intern() method.

```
if (op.intern() == "+") {}
```

Comment: (Nit Pick), but I, personally, would use `"+".equals(op)` as it avoids the possibility of a `NullPointerException`